# Prism RegionManager.Region[""].GetView("string") always returns null

Tags: wpf, prism, mef

I have an import in my view model for the regionmanager

```
[Import]
private IRegionManager _regionManager;
```

I want to be able to get a view and remove it from a region.

First step, get the view
i.e.

```
_regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].GetView("ViewName");
```

Whatever I do this always returns null. I specify a name for my view when adding it using view injection. When I try to use the above method though it doesn't work. I've seen other posts regarding this matter but none that seem to explain how to resolve it.

Comment: Have you looked within Views property of the IRegionManager to see if the view does in fact exist; or any view for that matter?

Comment: That's the thing - I can see that there are some views in there. The one I'm interested seems to be one of them. I can even see the Name set to the value I gave it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have sorted it out. Misunderstanding on my part.

When I was adding the view to my region I was using

```
View myView = new myView();
myView.Name = "ABC";
_regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].Add(myView);
```

This did not work when I tried GetView("ABC")

What I should have done was as follows

```
_regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].Add(myView, "asdf");
```

and then later on I can call

```
_regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].GetView("asdf");
```