# Is there any way to remove a view (by name) from a Prism region when the view was added using the RegionManager.RequestNavigate method?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation, prism

I am using [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) for navigation in my WPF MVVM application. I register my view as follows.

```cs
// MyView is the data type of the view I want to register and "MyView"
// is the name by which I want the data type to be identified within
// the IoC container.
_container.RegisterType<object, MyView>("MyView");
```

I display this view as follows.

```cs
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(
    "MyRegion", // This is the name of the Region where the view should be displayed.
    "MyView" // This is the registered name of the view in the IoC container.
);
```

Elsewhere in the application, I need to remove this view in an event handler; however, the following code returns an `ArgumentNullException`.

```cs
_regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"].Remove(
    _regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"].GetView("MyView")
);
```

This indicates that the `RequestNavigate` method does not add `MyView` to `MyRegion` using the name "MyView". I know that if I were to use the `_regionManager.Add(MyView, "MyView")` method, the `GetView` method would not return null. Unfortunately, `RequestNavigate` does not seem to handle the view name in the same way. Is there any way to remove a view (by name) from a region when the view was added using the `RequestNavigate` method?

Comment: After digging into the Prism source, it appears that `RequestNavigate` ultimately calls `region.Add(view);` (way down in `RegionNavigationContentLoader.LoadContent`). So as it stands, I don't think what I want to do is possible. I think it would be possible to implement this functionality by overloading the various `RequestNavigate` methods and extentions with an additional parameter for specifying the view name. This would allow views that have been added to a region using `RequestNavigate` to be accessed by name.

Comment: I've added your scenario explicitly to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It stems from how you add your view, not with your removal. [Previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475475/prism-regionmanager-region-getviewstring-always-returns-null) answered by adding the view fully, aka including the name.

```
_regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"].Add(myView, "MyView");
```

So now you can do your retrieval and removal:

```
var theView = _regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"].GetView("MyView");
_regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"].Remove(theView);
```

---

### Without defining name during Regions.Add()

In your View, define a property that is accessible (public if multi-project, internal if all in one project). Use this property in everything, one example would be a public string ViewTitle { get { return "XYZ"; } }.  Then retrieve from the Views the item that has the desired ViewTitle.  The Views collection is the collection of views in that region, so you can use dynamic in .NET 4.0+ to ignore the type and get the property/function you specify, assuming it is there.  Another option is to make your imported ViewModel in the View have a getter rather than just setting the DataContext, then you'd check the property "is" to the ViewModel you're looking for.  Removes the string search but exposes the view's datacontext.  So probably make an enum like I would do with the region.

I included everything in my View's .cs file so you can see how it works without complicating it or really breaking MVVM.

```
[ViewSortHint("050")]
[ViewExport(RegionName = RegionNames.WorkspaceTabRegion)]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public partial class AView : UserControl
{
    public AView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Import]
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1044:PropertiesShouldNotBeWriteOnly", Justification = "MEF requires property; never retrieved")]
    PrintingViewModel ViewModel { set { this.DataContext = value; } }

    public string ViewTitle { get { return "AView"; } }
}
```

Now in the ViewModel at some point:

```
   var viewToRemove = RegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.WorkspaceTabRegion].Views.FirstOrDefault<dynamic>(v => v.ViewTitle == "AView");
   RegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.WorkspaceTabRegion].Remove(viewToRemove);
```

Comment: Yes, but my question is specifically about the `RequestNavigate` method. If you read my comment you will see why this is not possible.

Comment: @odysseus.section9 Edited to include the section for this.

Comment: The second suggestion would actually work with `RequestNavigate`!

Comment: @odysseus.section9 Just make sure to have every single View with whatever you define in the lambda expression, be it property or function or field.  Otherwise you'll throw an exception and exit the LINQ search without a result. At least, applicable to whichever Views are in the Region(s) you'll be searching through.

Answer (score 3):

We recently found ourselves with the same problem; thanks @odysseus.section9 for pointing its root in your comment, it really helped.

We considered [making all views implement an interface having a Name property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699316/how-to-get-a-name-of-the-active-view-in-prism) but didn't feel quite right. Then we explored @bland solution but felt uncomfortable about using dynamic so we went for a very similar approach using **reflection**.

Since we are also already using the **[ViewExportAttribute](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/246402)** to export our views and it contains the desired ViewName property, what we do is querying for each view in a region for its attributes, looking for the ViewExportAttribute and checking the value of the **ViewName** property. Although in our design all views are annotated with it, the query tolerates views that don't - it simply ignores them.

For convenience we created an extension method for IRegion which searches for the views with the desired name within a region. Also, we added two extension methods to IRegionManager for two common scenarios in our application: re-using an existing view or navigating and removing all existing views (matching a name) and navigating. I think the latter solves your need just by getting rid of the call to

```
    public static IEnumerable<object> FindViews(this IRegion region, string viewName)
    {
        return from view in region.Views
               from attr in Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(view.GetType())
               where attr is ViewExportAttribute && ((ViewExportAttribute)attr).ViewName == viewName
               select view;
    }

    public static void ActivateOrRequestNavigate(this IRegionManager regionManager, string regionName, string viewName, UriQuery navigationParams)
    {
        IRegion region = regionManager.Regions[regionName];

        object view = region.FindViews(viewName).FirstOrDefault();
        if (view != null)
            region.Activate(view);
        else
            regionManager.RequestNavigate(regionName,
                new System.Uri(navigationParams != null ? viewName + navigationParams.ToString() : viewName, UriKind.Relative));
    }


    public static void RemoveAndRequestNavigate(this IRegionManager regionManager, string regionName, string viewName, UriQuery navigationParams)
    {
        IRegion region = regionManager.Regions[regionName];

        foreach (object view in region.FindViews(viewName))
            region.Remove(view);

        regionManager.RequestNavigate(regionName,
                new System.Uri(navigationParams != null ? viewName + navigationParams.ToString() : viewName, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```