# How to get a name of the active view in PRISM

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, prism-4

I am trying to navigate to the same view (same as the active one), but with new parameters. The problem is that I struggle to find a clean way to get a currently active view's name from RegionManager

Comment: The `IRegion` has an `ActiveViews` property that will give you a read-only collection of all currently active views.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @BrianS This collection inherits from IEnumerable<Object> which only has an actual view object, but not it's names. In other words active view doesn't provide any way to look up the actual name of the view.

Comment: I'm not clear on the design, and why you can't determine what view it is from the object.  Can you just create an `IMyView` interface with a `Name` property that all your views implement, then cast the object to `IMyView` and get the name of the view?

Comment: It sounds like you may have multiple instances of the same view in a Region, each with different parameters that differentiate it from the others.  Is that correct?  An you want to know which instance is currently active?

Comment: Yes, I have considered this option, but it's not great that you have to implement separate interface just in order to get round PRISM not exposing some of the private fields. I hope there is a cleaner way of doing that

Comment: What do you mean PRISM not exposing the private fields?  Private members, by their nature, are not exposed publicly - this is not a PRISM thing.  If you have an external component that needs to discover something about your object, it needs to be either `public` or `internal` (if the component is within the same assembly).  Using an interface to surface public properties is actually good practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding, I would recommend implementing an interface on each of your Views that provides the necessary information to determine which view it is, then use the `ActiveViews` property of the `IRegion` to access the active views.

Something like:

```
//Interface for identifying the Views
public interface IApplicationView
{
    string ViewName { get; }
}

//Example of a View with logic to determine which instance of the View it is
public class ApplicationView : UserControl, IApplicationView
{
    public string ViewName 
    { 
        get { return this.isViewA ? return "ViewA" : return "ViewB"; } 
    }
}

//Example of determining which view
public class OtherComponent
{
    public string GetActiveViewName(IRegion region)
    {
        IApplicationView activeView = region.ActiveViews.FirstOrDefault() as IApplicationView;
        return activeView == null ? string.Empty : activeView.ViewName;
    }
}
```

Comment: As fas as I can see there isn't a clean way to do it, so method above solves the problem.

Comment: Is there a way to get existing **ViewModel**s using the IoC container (in my case DryIoc)? I tried `this == _Container.Resolve<ShellViewModel>` from the `ShellViewModel` and it evaluated to `false`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this method is implemented in Prism 4. But in Prism 6, you can get the name of the active view using the `NavigationService` `Journal`.

For example:

```
string name = RegionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].NavigationService.Journal.CurrentEntry.Uri;
```